# How ${history} records how the program reached the final solution?

Tags: javascript, recursion

This example from Eloquent JS explains how recursion works.
 
I understand in general. BUT I couldn't get how `${history}` records the path toward the final solution.

I run  it in https://cutt.ly/1wFYrlQ

```js
function findSolution(target) {
   function find(current, history) {
     if (current == target) {
       return history;
     } else if (current > target) {
       return null;
     } else {
       return find(current + 5, `(${history} + 5)`) ||
       find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)`);
     } 
   }
   return find(1, "1"); 
}
console.log(findSolution(24)); // → (((1 * 3) + 5) * 3)
```

Just need to understand how the history binding works?

Comment: `\`\`` is a template literal in JS, which is like a string literal, but supports replacements by `${expression}` syntax. `\`(${history} + 5)\`` is equal to `"("+history+" + 5)"`

Comment: history is just a string that keeps extended in every call

Comment: The template literal confused me a little: it seems that history is working as current does but with strings: it is taking the string in parenthesis and pasting in history over and over again till the first condition is reached, right?

Answer (score -1):

In the example above you see  function `find(current, history)` being called from 
 return find(1, "1");  within function findSolution(target)

I have simplified that example it does the same thing

```js
  function find(current, history, target) {
      
   
        if (current == target) {
            return history;
        } else if (current > target) {
            return null;
        } else {
       
            return find(current + 5, `(${history} + 5)`, target) || find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)` , target );
        }
     
    }
  

console.log(find(1, "1", 88));
```

i will try to explain

`(${history} + 5)` is same as: '(' + history + 5 + ')'
since history is equal to "1" in the  first call, history = "(1 + 5)" as a string.

current is equal to 1 
current + 5 = 6,  history = "(1 + 5)", target 88 
now the function calls it self passing find(6, "(1 + 5)", 88)

next find calls it self again passing

```
find( 11, '(' + (1 + 5) + 5 + ')', 88 )
```

and the same process continue until if `(current == target)` gets true

Comment: What did you mean by wihid?

Comment: sorry i misspeld within

Comment: does this example make sense?